# How to create shared package.json for multiple npm repositories

Tags: node.js, npm

I am building my app using separated micro services, each has its own repository and npm dependencies and might be on a diffrent server.

I am looking for a way to put all of the dependencies in one global `package.json` file which can be accessed by url,
so in that way, I can update a shared dependency version, without running over all the different micro services, and update them one by one.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately npm doesn't support specifying parent package.json file. Such feature was [proposed some time ago](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8112), but npm maintainers come to conclusion that it should be achieved by external tools.

Of course you can write such tool yourself. There is one of possible aporaches:

1. Create library which contains `package.json` file with all shared dependencies. In this example it will be called `shared-deps`.
2. Create `merge.js` script which adds shared dependencies to local `package.json` file, and add it to `shared-deps` library:

   ```
   const fs = require('fs')

   const localPackageJson = require('../../package.json')
   const sharedPackageJson = require('./package.json')

   Object.assign(localPackageJson.dependencies, sharedPackageJson.dependencies)

   fs.writeFileSync('../../package.json', JSON.stringify(localPackageJson, null, 2))
   ```
3. Add to `package.json` of app which will be using this shared dependencies following post-install hook:

   ```
   "scripts": {
      "postinstall": "node ./node_modules/a/merge.js"
   }
   ```
4. Now, when you run `npm install`, your shared dependencies will be installed together with `shared-deps` library, and your `package.json` will be updated afterwards.

---

Comment: I don't understand. If this is put in postinstall, the merge is done *after* the install is done, and so how will the merged dependencies be installed ? Does that mean it needs to call 2 npm install in a row ?

Answer (score 1):

What if you create a new repository `shared-dependencies` with a `package.json` including all shared dependencies, then publishing it in npm.

After that you would be able to do `npm i shared-dependencies` on each main project therefore you'll have access to all shared dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [dry-dry](https://github.com/Cosium/dry-dry). Let's you define common `package.json` entries in one package and link to it from every package in the project.

Comment: This lib has no stars and is dead for years, without updates